# REST query string parameter NaN angular

Tags: angular, spring, rest, controller

Ok I have a REST Controller with this request

```html
@GetMapping("/search")
  @JsonView({PersonList.class})
  public ResponseEntity<?> search(@Valid PersonCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable) {
    final PersonType discriminant = criteria.getDiscriminant();
    if (null == discriminant || null == PersonType.from(discriminant.name())) {
      final String error = this.i18nSvc.get("svc.message.persons.type.missing");
      LOGGER.debug("[persons] Search method not possible: type of person not declared ! {}", error);
      return ErrorUtils.buildResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    try {

      final Page<? extends AbstractPerson> page = this.personService.search(criteria, pageable);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(page, HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (BusinessException e) {
      final String error = this.i18nSvc.get("svc.message.persons.type.invalid");
      LOGGER.debug("[persons] Search method not possible: type of person is invalid ! {}", error);
      return ErrorUtils.buildResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
  }
```

if I put a debug here I receive well my data but when I send a response to my angular front end app I receive  this in my response

```
http://localhost:8080/acmdemosvc/api/secure/persons/search?size=NaN&page=NaN&nom=e&discriminant=PP
```

So the query parameter are NaN. I am stuck on this. Is it a backend issue or front?

Comment: Please provide more info to work with.

Comment: what kind of info?

Comment: the response body in my browser is empty {}